# Getting "Unauthorized" Error while trying to get Oauth request_token from twitter API

Tags: java, twitter, authorization, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am trying to get  Oauth request_token from twitter API.
But when I am running the code, it is giving output "Unauthorized", though I am an authorized user.
Following is the output :

```
"parameter_string=oauth_consumer_key=MlyUxiF1ihXIymYIPWZCA&oauth_nonce=7ee1983904884d45b723f6cc50306617&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1385127328&oauth_version=1.0
signature_base_string=POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_consumer_key%3DMlyUxiF1ihXIymYIPWZCA%26oauth_nonce%3D7ee1983904884d45b723f6cc50306617%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1385127328%26oauth_version%3D1.0
oauth_signature=%2FOnHRfoRKyxPd9KG%2BA0HlFvE6yg%3D
authorization_header_string=OAuth oauth_consumer_key="MlyUxiF1ihXIymYIPWZCA",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1385127328",oauth_nonce="7ee1983904884d45b723f6cc50306617",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="%2FOnHRfoRKyxPd9KG%2BA0HlFvE6yg%3D"
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Unauthorized
"
```

And here is my full code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class TwitterConnection {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        // System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.classpath"));

        String oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

        String oauth_consumer_key = "MlyUxiF1ihXIymYIPWZCA";

        String uuid_string = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        uuid_string = uuid_string.replaceAll("-", "");

        String oauth_nonce = uuid_string; // any relatively random alphanumeric
                                            // string will work here. I used
                                            // UUID minus "-" signs

        long timestamp_at_entry = new Date().getTime();
        String oauth_timestamp = (new Long(timestamp_at_entry / 1000))
                .toString(); // get current time in milliseconds, then divide by
                                // 1000 to get seconds

        // I'm not using a callback value. Otherwise, you'd need to include it
        // in the parameter string like the example above

        // the parameter string must be in alphabetical order

        String parameter_string = "oauth_consumer_key=" + oauth_consumer_key
                + "&oauth_nonce=" + oauth_nonce + "&oauth_signature_method="
                + oauth_signature_method + "&oauth_timestamp="
                + oauth_timestamp + "&oauth_version=1.0";

        System.out.println("parameter_string=" + parameter_string);

        String signature_base_string = "POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&"
                + URLEncoder.encode(parameter_string, "UTF-8");

        System.out.println("signature_base_string=" + signature_base_string);

        String oauth_signature = "";

        try {

            oauth_signature = computeSignature(signature_base_string,
                    "122595245-sPcfsJO3GRkJpjzgFLZ918OaHkxeSmwYg9WDn23Z"); // note
                                                                            // the
                                                                            // &
                                                                            // at
                                                                            // the
                                                                            // end.
                                                                            // Normally
                                                                            // the
                                                                            // user
                                                                            // access_token
                                                                            // would
                                                                            // go
                                                                            // here,
                                                                            // but
                                                                            // we
                                                                            // don't
                                                                            // know
                                                                            // it
                                                                            // yet
                                                                            // for
                                                                            // request_token

            System.out.println("oauth_signature="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(oauth_signature, "UTF-8"));

        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        String authorization_header_string = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\""
                + oauth_consumer_key
                + "\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"" +

                oauth_timestamp + "\",oauth_nonce=\"" + oauth_nonce
                + "\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\""
                + URLEncoder.encode(oauth_signature, "UTF-8") + "\"";

        System.out.println("authorization_header_string="
                + authorization_header_string);

        String oauth_token = "";

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {

//          HttpParams params = new SyncBasicHttpParams();
//          HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
//          HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");
//          HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(params, "HttpCore/1.1");
//          HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, false);
//
//          HttpProcessor httpproc = new ImmutableHttpProcessor(
//                  new HttpRequestInterceptor[] {
//                          // Required protocol interceptors
//                          new RequestContent(), new RequestTargetHost(),
//                          // Recommended protocol interceptors
//                          new RequestConnControl(), new RequestUserAgent(),
//                          new RequestExpectContinue() });
//
//          HttpRequestExecutor httpexecutor = new HttpRequestExecutor();
//          HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext(null);
//          HttpHost host = new HttpHost(
//                  "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", 443); // use
//                                                                          // 80
//                                                                          // if
//                                                                          // you
//                                                                          // want
//                                                                          // regular
//                                                                          // HTTP
//                                                                          // (not
//                                                                          // HTTPS)
//          DefaultHttpClientConnection conn = new DefaultHttpClientConnection();
//
//          context.setAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_CONNECTION, conn);
//          context.setAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST, host);
//
//          // initialize the HTTPS connection
//          SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
//          sslcontext.init(null, null, null);
//          SSLSocketFactory ssf = sslcontext.getSocketFactory();

            // for HTTP, use this instead of the above.
            // Socket socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), host.getPort());
            // conn.bind(socket, params);

//          BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest request2 = new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest(
//                  "POST", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
//          request2.setEntity(new StringEntity("",
//                  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "UTF-8"));
//          request2.setParams(params);
//          request2.addHeader("Authorization", authorization_header_string); // this
//                                                                              // is
//                                                                              // where
//                                                                              // we're
//                                                                              // adding
//                                                                              // that
//                                                                              // required
//                                                                              // "Authorization: BLAH"
//                                                                              // header.
//          httpexecutor.preProcess(request2, httpproc, context);
//          HttpResponse response2 = httpexecutor.execute(request2, conn,
//                  context);
//          //
             HttpPost httppost = new
             HttpPost("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");

             httppost.setHeader("Authorization",authorization_header_string);


             ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new
             BasicResponseHandler();

             String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost,
             responseHandler);

             oauth_token =
             responseBody.substring(responseBody.indexOf("oauth_token=") + 12,
             responseBody.indexOf("&oauth_token_secret="));

             System.out.println(responseBody);

        }

        catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
            System.out.println(cpe.getMessage());
        }

        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }

        finally {
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }

    private static String computeSignature(String baseString, String keyString)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        SecretKey secretKey = null;

        byte[] keyBytes = keyString.getBytes();

        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA1");

        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");

        mac.init(secretKey);

        byte[] text = baseString.getBytes();

        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(mac.doFinal(text))).trim();

    }

}
```

I would like to know, how do I solve this and get the request_token.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a library like [Signpost](https://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/). Creating the signature with all the right params and & separators is always tricky and you seem to be doing all of it. If you are just trying it for academic reasons then read up the rfc!

Comment: Hi, I am using Signpost as you suggested, but when I wrote the program and gave respective credentials of my application, It is failing saying
Exception in thread "main" oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException: Request token or token secret not set in server reply. The service provider you use is probably buggy.
 at oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(DefaultOAuthProvider.java:138)
 at oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(DefaultOAuthProvider.java:66)at Main.main(Main.java:30)"Would like to know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your consumer key is `122595245-sPcfsJO3GRkJpjzgFLZ918OaHkxeSmwYg9WDn23Z`, you need to append an ampersand character to the end to get the signing key, as per your notes.

Your signature base string is correct (except for the oauth_callback parameter - see below), so your code may be generating an incorrect signature. You can check your signature using an online signature generator such as the [LinkedIn OAuth Test Console](https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console).

You don't appear to have included the oauth_callback parameter in your calculation. This needs to be set to the url that you want the user to be redirected to when they have authorized your app, or 'oob' for PIN based authorization.

By the way, if the above code includes your actual consumer key and consumer secret, I would not post them on a public forum.